# Get A Collection of Data and Limit Them by Start and End Date

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, scope

I have SpecialPrice Model that hold data based on start_date & end_date columns like the following screen

[image]

what i want to achieve is the following  :

1. if user select date from 2020-04-23 to 2020-04-26 i should retrieve the first object only.
2. but if user select date from 2020-04-23 to 2020-04-27 i should retrieve first & second objects only.
3. but if user select date from 2020-04-23 to 2020-05-01 i should retrieve the three objects etc.

In my model i have scoped function and i tried however i know it has something wrong

```
public function scopeBetweenDates($query,$start_date , $end_date){
    return $query->whereRaw('? between start_date and end_date', [$start_date])
                ->orWhereRaw('? between start_date and end_date', [$end_date]);
}
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
public function scopeWhereIntersectsStartDate($query,$start_date){

    return  $query->whereNotNull('start_date')
                  ->where('start_date' , '>' , $start_date)
                  ->orWhere('end_date' , '>' , $start_date);
}

public function scopeWhereIntersectsEndDate($query,$end_date){

    return  $query->whereNotNull('end_date')
                  ->where('end_date' , '<' , $end_date)
                  ->orWhere('start_date' , '<' , $end_date);
}
```